# Bad repaint behavior of JMapPane

Tags: java, swing, geotools

I'm trying to develop a moving map application based on [geotools12RC1](http://geotools.org/) libary. EDIT: Will be updated to 12.1 as soon as i have the time.

Currently I'm loading shape files, applying sld styles and display the resulting layers within a JMapPane. I've added zoom in, zoom out and pan buttons via the provided actions of geotools.

When I zoom in and out the pane is calculating the area and then repaints itself, while the calculation you're still seeing the "old" image. But on pan the pane is cleared the moment, the repaint method is invoked, the result is you're seeing a white frame until repaint is finished. That isn't acceptable for a moving map, so i would like to know if there is a way to clear the pane after the calculations are finished and the image only needs to be drawn, that would result that you can see the map all the time.

Comment: First I'd move to 12.1 http://geotoolsnews.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/geotools-121-released.html as there is no telling which bugs we fixed. Then we need to see your action handler code to see what you are doing.

Comment: I've used the maven pom.xml from the quickstart and haven't noticed that a newer release is available, I'll fix this. Cheers for that. I don't know which action handler you need, for the zoom and pan buttons I've used the http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/unsupported/swing/jmappane.html#actions as mentioned above. I could imagine that this actions are the inefficient code